# Script 404 errors in Adobe ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have below code in ColdFusion.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <cfform id="form1" name="form1" method="post">

        <cfquery name="config" datasource="config">
            SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName
            FROM tablename
        </cfquery>

        <cfinput name="ColumnName"
            type="text"
            autoSuggest="#valueList(config.ColumnName)#"
            typeahead="true"
            size="40"
            placeholder="ColumnName"/><br>

    </cfform>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem occurs at this line: `autoSuggest="#valueList(config.ColumnName)#"`

Below are the errors in console. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per **[official page of Adobe ColdFusion 2016](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/deprecated-features.html)**, I will have to **[download js and css manually for yui from here](https://cfdownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/coldfusion/2016/deprecated_features/yui.zip)**

*Relevant information from the linked article:*

> **YUI and Spry**
>   We have deprecated YUI and Spry libraries in ColdFusion 2016 (Update 3) and removed the following JavaScript libraries:
>
> `<cfusion_webroot>\cf_scripts\scripts\ajax\yui`
>   `<cfusion_webroot>\cf_scripts\scripts\ajax\spry`
>   `<cfusion_webroot>\cf_scripts\scripts\ajax\resources\yui`
>
> As a result, the following tags that use the YUI and Spry features would be impacted:
>
> - cfmenu
> - cftree
> - cftooptip
> - cfcalendar
> - cfinput (autosuggest attribute)
> - cfinput (sourcefortooltip attribute)
> - cfsprydataset
>
> As a workaround, you can manually download the removed files from the following locations and copy them in ColdFusion's webroot, at the directories listed above.
>
> - [YUI](https://cfdownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/coldfusion/2016/deprecated_features/yui.zip) (Checksum: 827e0f8395d176ac28f46ed5e78004fd)
> - [Spry](https://cfdownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/coldfusion/2016/deprecated_features/spry.zip) (Checksum: 750c275c20b291f00c1ba92c855a09d7)

Comment: You should always include the relevant text from any external sources. That way the information will not be lost on SO if the original source is removed. Don't forget to accept your answer as the solution.

Comment: What about cflayout? Mine seems to rely on the yui folder...